# Blog items and portfolio items with a different parent

Tags: wordpress, parent

i'm stuck in trying to solve this problem.
I'm editing a premade theme and i'm trying to get the following:

**for portfolio item > www.mysite.com/portfolio/item**

**for blog item > www.mysite.com/blog/item**

The problem is that if i edit the "permalinks" adding /blog/ in the custom entries i'll get the following:

*for portfolio item > www.mysite.com/blog/portfolio/item*

*for blog item > www.mysite.com/blog/item*

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup your portfolio post type, you'll want to set it's 'with_front' parameter to false:

```
$args = array(
  //Other arguments would go here...
  'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false )
)
register_post_type('portfolio',$args);
```

This should allow you to use '/blog' for all other posts, but will remove '/blog' from the URL of portfolio posts